# Image to Tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place a image into my tkinter window and getting error not sure what is causing it. The path is 100% to the location on my computer.

```
import tkinter

import os

from PIL import ImageTk, Image


#Actual window        
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
window.title('Game')
window.configure(bg = 'Indian red')

#Pictures
path = 'E:\Hack Things\python\amazonlogo'
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

#Buttons
start = tkinter.Button(text = 'Start', height = 5, width = 25, font =
('Helvetica', 12))

start.place(relx = .5, rely = .25, anchor='c')

options = tkinter.Button(text="Options")
options.place(relx = .5, rely = .45, anchor='c')

exitbutton = tkinter.Button(text = 'Exit Game', command = quit, height = 5, 
width = 15, fg = 'red')
exitbutton.place(relx = .5, rely = .85, anchor='c')

window.mainloop()
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Hack Things\python\start.py", line 16, in <module>
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
  File "C:\Users\Ihas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2477, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\Hack Things\\python\x07mazonlogo'
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use raw string (by adding a `r` in front the quotes). Or escape the back slashes (by adding a `\` in front every `\`). Since the [`\a`](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) has a special meaning which is “ASCII Bell (BEL)”

```
path = r'E:\Hack Things\python\amazonlogo'
```